# moz-placeholder does not work in Firefox

Tags: css

Please see the code below, the CSS for the placeholder does not work in the Firefox (latest version), but it works fine with the Chrome. How can I fix it for Firefox?

There are multiple input colors for the fields, but I only one color for the placeholder, so I do not want to specify any class name in the moz-placeholder property, so that it applies to all input fields.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" placeholder="some text asdf" value="" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:red; }
::-moz-placeholder { color:red; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color:red; }

.row input[type="text"]{
     color: blue;     
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/C6fjh/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'ts working, it's just that the last rule is considered more specific by Firefox. Try this:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:red; }
.row input[type="text"]::-moz-placeholder { color:red; }
.row input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder { color:red; }

.row input[type="text"] {
     color: blue;     
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6fjh/2/) for a working demo.

I'm unsure where the difference in browsers comes from, or which one is "correct". A [similar experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/nDNdg/2/) with `a` tag and `:hover` pseudo class shows the same behavior in both FF and Chrome: both will ignore the pseudo class color if the element's selector is more specific (and if you make the same change as I suggested above you get the same [(expected?) behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/nDNdg/3/) in both Chrome and FF).

Comment: The selector `:-moz-placeholder` is a pseudo-class, so the combined selector matches the `input` element as a real element (in placeholder display state), but in the original CSS code, that element has its color set by a rule with a more specific selector. In contrast, `::-webkit-input-placeholder` is a pseudo-element that corresponds to the placeholder text only. Firefox is about to move to use a pseudo-element for placeholder, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:-moz-placeholder

Comment: Another tip, if you need your colors to display properly, is add: 'opacity: 1;' I am using FF 20.0.1 and it will dim the placeholder to less than 100% opacity. Try setting the background-color to 'black' and see that it appears gray. With opacity: 1, it is true black.

Comment: Thank you Neil, that was driving me crazy. I would have never thought to apply opacity: 1.

Comment: @NeilMonroe, I know it's an old subject, but your answer is the correct one. Perhaps you should expain it as an answer instead of a comment. It seems even new versions of Firefox reduce the opacity of the placeholders, so the difference of the colors is due to it. Btw: `opacity: 1` into the `::moz-placeholder` selector worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @NeilMonroe Feel free to suggest it as an edit to my answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 14):

In some cases the red color will show lighter in Mozilla as compared to Chrome or IE. In that case you need to add opacity:1 to it too.

E.g.

`:-moz-placeholder { color: red; opacity:1;}
::-moz-placeholder { color: red; opacity:1;}`

Comment: `opacity:1;` is what I was missing. Thanks