# Can a placeholder change its color (validate) when the field is required?

Tags: validation, placeholder, contact-form

I'm trying to make a placeholder validation effect that when a field is required, its placeholder changes its color form white to red. Please help me with this. I've tried webkits and bootstrap "control label" but its not working properly. With the control label class its working properly on firefox but not in google chrome.

This is what i've tried

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" required="required" class="control-label text-fields" placeholder="Name"  />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="number" required="required" class="control-label text-fields" placeholder="Phone" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="control-label field" type="text" rows="2" placeholder="Address" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="control-label field" type="text" rows="1" placeholder="Comments" required></textarea>
    </div>


    <CSS>
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
       color: white;
    }

    input:required {
        color:#red !important;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    input:valid {
        color:#fff !important;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    textarea:required {
        color:#red !important;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

    textarea:valid {
        color:#fff !important;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: This is the css

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: white;
}

input:required {
 color:#red !important;
 box-shadow: none;
}

input:valid {
 color:#fff !important;
 box-shadow: none;
}

textarea:required {
 color:#red !important;
 box-shadow: none;
}

textarea:valid {
 color:#fff !important;
 box-shadow: none;
}

Comment: Put it in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[required]` attribute selector to add the color just to required fields.

```css
[required]::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    red;
}
[required]::-moz-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    red;
}
[required]::-ms-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    color:    red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="not required" />
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="required" required/>
```

Comment: Thanks you sir but the placeholders are now showing red before i even press the submit button..

Comment: Why shouldn't they? The fields are required. Did you mean you wanted to use the placeholder as the way to show that they didn't fill in a required field?

Comment: Yes that what i mean't. Please do you have any solution?

Comment: and one more thing.. its only working in chrome not in firefox

Comment: Instead of using the `required` attribute, do your validation in Javascript, and change the class. Then you can use `.validation-failed::-webkit-input-placeholder`

Comment: Regarding Firefox, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014329/moz-placeholder-does-not-work-in-firefox